# Custom Validator OnserverValidate call Class function

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to call cetralized class function ONservervalidate for a custom validator, So I don't have to write it on each and every page. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a Modul or Class with a shared function as your servervalidate-function. You have to add the handler of the event manually:

aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ValidateEmptyText="true" ErrorMessage="Validator said NO!" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

codebehind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     AddHandler Me.CustomValidator1.ServerValidate, AddressOf ValidatorUtil.myFunction
 End Sub
```

reusable Validator-Class:

```
Public NotInheritable Class ValidatorUtil
    Public Shared Sub myFunction(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As ServerValidateEventArgs)
        'validate here and set IsValid'
        args.IsValid = False
    End Sub

End Class
```